# Как передать данные из win-приложения в node.js?

Tags: node.js, http

На одной машине есть win-приложение и node.js приложение. Win-приложение должно примерно каждые 500мс передавать данные в ноду. Проблема в том, что единственными путями вывода инфы из этого приложения - это возможность отправлять HTTP запросы или же выводить эту инфу в файл, что-то вроде логов. Так же приложение, осуществляющее вывод должно знать, что оно отдает данные не "в пустоту". Как в этом случае лучше поступить? Я правильно понимаю, что через HTTP это нормально реализовать не выйдет из-за того, что сервер на ноде из-за такой частоты запросов просто сляжет?

Comment: Это с какого перепуга оно ляжет?

Comment: @Aziz Umarov т.е если 24/7 такая канитель будет на машине работать, то ничего критичного?

Comment: Вы поймите вы строите проблему не начав решать задачу. А так не делают. Пусть упадет потом будите решать почему это так.

Comment: Зависит от того что же нода делает с этими запросами. Причём, судя по вашему описанию, она по любому должна их как-то обрабатывать. Сферическая нода в вакуупе эти 2rps даже не заметит.

Comment: поддерживаю комментарий @AlexeyTen. дополню: и 200rps тоже спокойно. и " приложение, осуществляющее вывод должно знать, что оно отдает данные не "в пустоту"" - по http ты всегда знаешь статус своего запроса, ты всегда знаешь обработал ли он или ошибка обработки или улетел в пустоту (или что делать дальше (например, номер задания в очереди))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не пойму почему у вас должен лечь node.js

1. Если вы так уж думаете о нагрузке, то реализуйте очередь.
2. Записывайте запрос в очередь и возращяйте ответ с номером в очереди.
3. Наблюдайте за статусом запроса по id в очереди.

А по хорошему делается от простого к сложному. Важно разделить на куски чтоб можно было работать. Вопросы оптимизации, утечки памяти и прочего решаются по мере поступления. Конечно если у вас есть валидный построенный проверенный шаблон то пользуйтесь им. Все остальное как с ребёнком. Растить и ухаживать и возможно со временим если оно станет таким как вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо,  просто были некие сомнения в работоспособности этой схемы, буду пробовать на практике :)

Comment: @lokit68490 отправить запрос это не проблема. Важно что делать по данному запросу. Вот это важно понимать.